# Using the results of a query in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, oracle10g, openquery

I have a SQL Server 2005 database that is linked to an Oracle database.  What I want to do is run a query to pull some ID numbers out of it, then find out which ones are in Oracle.

So I want to take the results of this query:

```
SELECT pidm
FROM sql_server_table
```

And do something like this to query the Oracle database (assuming that the results of the previous query are stored in @pidms):

```
OPENQUERY(oracledb,
'
SELECT pidm
FROM table
WHERE pidm IN (' +
@pidms + ')')
GO
```

But I'm having trouble thinking of a good way to do this.  I suppose that I could do an inner join of queries similar to these two. Unfortunately, there are a lot of records to pull within a limited timeframe so I don't think that will be a very performant option to choose.

Any suggestions?  I'd ideally like to do this with as little Dynamic SQL as possible.

Comment: Can you add the Oracle server as a linked server so that you can use joining syntax instead of calling OPENQUERY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhhh, pidms.  Brings back bad memories!  :)

You could do the join, but you would do it like this:

```
select sql.pidm,sql.field2 from sqltable as sql
inner join
(select pidm,field2 from oracledb..schema.table) as orcl
on 
sql.pidm = orcl.pidm
```

I'm not sure if you could write a PL/SQL procedure that would take a table variable from sql...but maybe.....no, I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Store openquery results in a temp table, then do an inner join between the SQL table and the temp table.

Comment: But wouldn't that pull in the entire table unless I know the ids that I need from the first query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do a join since OPENQUERY requires a pure string (as you wrote above).

Answer (score 0):

BG: Actually JOIN IN SQLServer to Oracle by OpenQuery works, avoiding #tmp table and allowing JOIN to SQL without Param* - ex.

```
[SQL SP] LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(ORADB,
'SELECT  COUNT(distinct O.ORD_NUM) LCNT, 
 O.ORD_MAIN_NUM  
 FROM CUSTOMER.CUST_FILE C
 JOIN CUSTOMER.ORDER_NEW O 
 ON C.ID = O.ORD_ID
 WHERE  C.CUS_ID NOT IN (''2'',''3'') 
 GROUP BY O.ORD_MAIN_MACNUM') LC 
 ON T.ID = LC.ORD_MAIN_ID*
```

Cheers, Bill Gibbs